# Load test Java application with 3rd party web services

Tags: java, load-testing, rest-api

I have a Spring Boot application and need to perform load and stress tests in order toestimate the resources my production server will need and configure my auto scaling metrics.
But the major part of my application is heavily consuming and posting data to one 3rd party SOAP web service and sometimes does the same with one RESTful api.
What is the best way to load test my application.
Is it valid that I mock the SOAP and REST webservices? If so what is the best method?
Or the only valid way is to use the real services that will be consumed in production? (I wanted to avoid to polute de database of the provider)

Answer (score 1):

If they are 3rd-party providers and/or consumers I believe it is fine to mock the services, moreover it is recommended to [exclude external resources from load tests](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test) as this is not something you can control so it would be better to limit your 3rd party integrations testing to [profiling](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html) the relevant code or using [code analysis tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#Java) to find potential performance problems or memory leaks.